# UIBezierPath does not change color and is not added to the view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

There is an implementation like this:

```
class EllupseTest: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       
        let views = MyView(frame: CGRect(x: 36.62, y: 77.54, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
        views.backgroundColor = .clear
        views.rotate(degrees: 45.84)

        view.addSubview(views)
    }
}


class Ellipse: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 303.19, height: 495.93))
        UIColor.cyan.setFill()
        path.fill()
    }
}
```

But if I want to change the color, the rectangle will be colored, not the ellipse itself (that's why I put `views.backgroundColor = .clear` for a while) How can I change the color of the ellipse itself, and not its rectangle?

I read that you can use PaintCode, but I don't understand how to add it to the view via `view.addSubview ()`. How to add to a view

Here is the code from PaintCode

```
//// General Declarations
let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!

//// Color Declarations
let color = UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.773, blue: 0.620, alpha: 1.000)

//// Oval Drawing
context.saveGState()
context.translateBy(x: 610, y: -139)
context.rotate(by: 90 * CGFloat.pi/180)

let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 314.87, height: 515.04))
color.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()

context.restoreGState()
```

I work with UIBezierPath for the first time)

Comment: What does change color mean? I don’t see any “change color” code.

Comment: You have hard-coded `UIColor.cyan.setFill()`. If that's not what you want, don't do that.

Comment: And `MyView` is not the same as `Ellipse` view